# Permutation for arrays in php

Tags: php, algorithm, permutation

lets say I have the followings array

```
$data = array
(
  '1' => array(5, 6, 7),
  '2' => array(9, 25, 14),

);
```

I am trying write a permutations function which will make sure the value maintains the key position in the array. For example following combinations

```
    array(
     (int) 0 => array(
      (int) 1 => 5,
      (int) 2 => 25,
     (int) 3 => 14,


     ),
    (int) 1 => array(
      (int) 1 => 9,
      (int) 2 => 6,
      (int) 3 => 7

     ),
     )
```

are correct but the following combination is not correct

```
 array(
    (int) 0 => array(
    (int) 1 => 25,
    (int) 2 => 6,
    (int) 3 => 7,
    ),
     )
```

Sorry for not being able to explain it in a better way.Can anybody please help me with  the logic of this..thanks